# JSONP json callback method not called : parsererror

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I have the following ajax function using jsonp:

```
    function PopulateDivisions1()
{
    $.support.cors=true;


    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'http://IP/Service/api/DivisionSearch/GetAllDivisions?callback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        //jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",

        success: function(data) {

                alert('yes');

                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val("-99").html("Select One"));
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                $("#divisionSelect").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Name).html(item.Name));
            });
        },
        error: function(xhrequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("Original: " + thrownError + " : " + ErrorText);
        }
    });


}
```

I am getting the following error: 
        myJsonMethod was not called : parsererror

If I look at Fiddler, I am getting the following data back, I added the callback name to the front, as I saw that suggested, if I take it out it still doesn't work.

```
    "myJsonMethod([{\"Id\":1,\"Description\":\"Executive\",\"Name\":\"Executive \"},{\"Id\":2,\"Description\":\"ASD\",\"Name\":\"Administrative Services Division \"},{\"Id\":3,\"Description\":\"COM\",\"Name\":\"Communications \"},{\"Id\":4,\"Description\":\"CP\",\"Name\":\"Contracts and Procurement \"},{\"Id\":5,\"Description\":\"PMD\",\"Name\":\"Program Management Division \"},{\"Id\":6,\"Description\":\"RED\",\"Name\":\"Research and Evaluation Division \"},{\"Id\":7,\"Description\":\"IT\",\"Name\":\"Information Technology \"}])"
```

Here is the method in my controller:

```
     public string GetAllDivisions(string callback)
    {
        var divisions = _DivisionModel.GetAllDivisions();

        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string json = serializer.Serialize(divisions);

        string result = callback + "(" + json + ");";

        return result; 
    }
```

I'm not getting to my success call, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to specify a success callback because the jsonp callback will happen automatically as the server side code will return javascript in case of jsonp.

Refer the below answer for working example.

[Using jquery jsonp returns error callback function was not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351934/using-jquery-jsonp-returns-error-callback-function-was-not-called/19423625#19423625)